# defining inverse error function

Tags: inverse-function, error-function

The error function is define like this: $$\operatorname{erf}(x):=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$$

If i take the derivative i get $$\operatorname{erf'}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}$$because say $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(G(x)-G(0)\right)$$and $G(0)$ is constant.

---

Because $\forall x,\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}>0$ we know that $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ is strictly increasing, so it suppose to have an inverse function.

I can understand few of things about $\operatorname{erf^{-1}}(x)$:

> - the domain is $\operatorname{erf}((-\infty,\infty))=(-1,1)$
> - the codomain is $(-\infty,\infty)$
> - 3 points:
>
>   > - $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\operatorname{erf}(x)=1\implies\lim\limits_{x\to1}\operatorname{erf^{-1}}(x)=\infty$
>   > - $\operatorname{erf}(0)=0\implies \operatorname{erf^{-1}}(0)=0$
>   > - $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\operatorname{erf}(x)=-1\implies\lim\limits_{x\to-1}\operatorname{erf^{-1}}(x)=-\infty$
> - it is strictly increasing

---

But apart from those 4 things I can't think about any other information.

So my question is the following: **Is there a way to define inverse error function using combination of known functions and transforms? And if not, what more can we know about the inverse function?**

Comment: You might look at L. Carlitz, [The inverse of the error function](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103035736), Pacific J. Math. Volume 13, Number 2 (1963), 459-470, for some properties of the Maclaurin series $$\text{erf}^{-1}(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} x}{2} + \frac{\pi^{3/2} x^3}{24} + \frac{7 \pi^{5/2} x^5}{960} + \ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

**As a Special Case** $\def \erf{\operatorname{erf}}$

Let’s use a more general inverse function implemented called [**Inverse Gamma Regularized**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inversegammaregularized) which existed before $2000$ in Mathematica, so it is a well established function. It finds the quantile of a cdf based on [Gamma Regularized $Q(a,z)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html). There also exists [**Gamma P Inverse**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RxODE/versions/1.1.0/topics/gammapInv) for the inverse with respect to $z$ for [$\text P(a,z)=1-Q(a,z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). The inverse functions are quantile functions for [Incomplete Gamma function based distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) and $\erf ^{-1}$ is the quantile function for the [Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution):

$$Q(a,z)=\frac{\int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt}{\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt}=y\mathop\implies^{a,z\ge0} z=Q^{-1}(a,y)$$

$$\text P(a,z)=\frac{\int_0^x t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt}{\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt}=y\mathop\implies^{a,z\ge0} z=\text{gammapinv}(a,y)=Q^{-1}(a,1-x)\ \ \ \text {”=“}\ \ \ \text P^{-1}(a,x)$$

Notice that:

$$1-Q\left(\frac12,y^2\right)=\text P\left(\frac12,y^2\right)=\text{erf}(y)=x\implies y=\boxed{\sqrt{Q^{-1}\left(\frac12,1-x\right)}=\sqrt{\text{gammapinv}\left(\frac12,x\right)}\mathop=^{x\ge0}\erf^{-1}(x)}$$

Here is a graph:

[image]

These identities give another special case of $Q^{-1}(a,z)$. Please correct me and give me feedback!

**Other Differential Equation:**

Here is a simpler differential equation based off of @Fraklin Pezzuti Dyer’s solution:

$$y=\erf^{-1}(x):y’= \frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{y^2} \implies y’’= \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{y^2}}_{y’}yy’\implies \boxed{y’’=2y’^2y\iff y=\text{erf}^{-1}(c_0x+c_1)}$$

**Integral Representation:**

The following is experimental, but

$$\erf^{-1}(x)=\frac{\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}}2\int_{-1}^1\erf^{-1}(t)\csc\left(\frac\pi2(t-x)\right)\sin\left(\pi m(t-x)\right)dt=\frac{\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty te^{-t^2}\csc\left(\frac\pi2(\erf(t)-x)\right)\sin\left(\pi m(\erf(t)-x)\right)dt,|x|<1 $$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=erf%28Nintegrate%5Bt+%28%282+e%5E%28-t%5E2%29%29%2Fsqrt%28%CF%80%29%29+1%2F2+csc%281%2F2+%CF%80+%28erf%28t%29+-+0.4%29%29+sin%28%28+40+%29+%CF%80+%28erf%28t+%29-+0.4%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C-infty%2Cinfty%7D%5D%29)

Comment: `InverseErf` is currently implemented in Mathematica.

Comment: @Anixx That is how it was plotted in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that
$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{(f'\circ f^{-1})(x)}$$
and so we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\text{erf}^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{(\text{erf}'\circ \text{erf}^{-1} )(x)}$$
or
$$\frac{d}{dx}\text{erf}^{-1}(x)=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}e^{(\text{erf}^{-1}(x))^2}$$
and so the inverse error function can be defined by the differential equation
$$y'=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\exp (y^2)$$
with initial condition $y(0)=0$.